# Fedora 19 XFCE screen rotation

Tags: fedora, xorg, xfce, xrandr, display-rotation

I am trying to make screen rotation setting persist after reboot (without having to run a script on boot).

I am using the XFCE spin of Fedora 19.

I can make the screen rotate as I want it to using the xrandr command:

```
xrandr -o left
```

After reboot the screen is back to normal, not rotated to the left.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue by adding a "Monitor" section to the xorg.conf file.

The part that needed to be added is listed blow;

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "monitor"
    Option     "Rotate" "Left"
EndSection
```

You then need to reference the monitor in the screen section:

```
Section "Screen"
        Identifier "Screen0"
        Device     "Videocard0"
        Monitor    "monitor"  #<----- This line
        DefaultDepth     24
        SubSection "Display"
                Modes "1280x720"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     24
        EndSubSection
EndSection
```